# CSS !important rule not overriding text alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, css-specificity

```
a {
        font-size: 8pt;
        text-align: left !important;
        text-decoration: none;
  }

.main {
        text-align: center;
  }

 <div class="main">
    <a href="#new_york_city">New York City</a><br />
    <a href="#long_island">Long Island</a><br />
    <a href="#upstate">Upstate New York</a><br />
</div>
```

This is a compact version of what I have and for me, using Firefox 5, the links are STILL centered, even though I I'm using !important on the "text-align: left".  It's confusing and irritating because i thought !important was the highest specificity and overrode all other rules.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Whoopsy, had a bit of a dumb moment there.  Yeah, just realized the container has to have the alignments, not the text/links, so setting 'text-align: left' on them essentially does nothing.  I did find, however, that 'float: left' works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text alignment needs to be set on the parent element of the anchor-links, you cannot tell an anchor-link to align itself to the left as it is of a fixed width. You need to either remove `text-align:center;` from the .main section, or add another class to the div like 'alignLeft' and apply the alignment with the `!important` rule there.

Answer (score 1):

The links themselves are centered. Wrap them in something else and left align that.

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="left">
    <a href="#new_york_city">New York City</a><br />
    <a href="#long_island">Long Island</a><br />
    <a href="#upstate">Upstate New York</a><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you're doing, this may work:

```
.main a {
  display:block;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: left !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Text-align can only work on a block element (such as a div). "span" and "a" are inline by default, but display:block can change that.

Answer (score 1):

An anchor is an `inline` element by default, which in your case means it's only as wide as it needs to be, so it really is aligning left but only within itself.  Since it's nested within `main` presumably a block element, `main` in centering the `a` tag.

Either put the anchor in another block element and align that left, or set it to block.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because your `a` links are `inline` elements without a specified width.  There is nothing to center because the entire element is the width of the `a`.

To fix this, either

1. set the `.main div` to `text-align:left;` or
2. wrap the `a` links in a `p` and give it `text-align:left;`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGfxu/), you'll see that the links are still `inline` and therefore, the text's alignment doesn't count for anything (since the element will collapse around its contents).

If you make the links `inline-blocks` or `blocks` with a defined width, you can justify the text within them, as shown in [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGfxu/1/).

Now, if you want the links up against the left side of the container, `float:left` as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGfxu/2/).